# javascript : add a property dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

Following is a snippet of a big file, written using node.js.
Array of user objects have been sent to a function. If frequency is defined for that user, I want to add that as a property to user object but in vain.

```
var usersFromActiveDomains = []; 
function sample (users) {
  _.forEach (  users , function ( user ) {
    var freq = getFrequency(user);
    if(freq) {
      user.frequency = freq;
      usersFromActiveDomains.push(user);
      console.log('user', user);
    } 
  });
  return usersFromActiveDomains;
}
```

Comment: `user` is a new object created during the iteration method; it will not update the `users` array. You'll need to iterate using and index and overwrite the array by using `users[idx]`.

Comment: thanks remus, however, i did edit the post to correct my question.

Comment: Your function doesn't have a name. How are you calling it? Is it a callback and you're not showing the rest of the code?

Comment: Is freq ever defined? Console.log to confirm.

Comment: I'm not showing the rest of the code. Written a sample code that mimic the issue that i'm facing. Adding the function name for more readable code.

Comment: @remus, yes, freq is defined, confirmed.
I've given a static value 'test' to user.frequency for testing.
console.log('user',user) is not printing the frequency property.

Comment: @Andy, this function is a part of a Promise, I need to return usersFromActiveDomains..
No error message, it's just not adding this property to user object,hence the other function that receives usersFromActiveDomains does not find 'frequency' property.

Comment: @andy, using _.map didn't help.

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to tell what's going on from this, since we don't have all the facts.  However, I'd guess that "freq" is returning false, thereby leaving "usersFromActiveDomains" empty.  I made a working jsfiddle for your reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/b62a0arr/

Here's the code:

```
var usersFromActiveDomains = [],
   baseUsers = [
      {
        name: "sam"
      },
      {
        name: "julie"
      },
      {
        name: "jimbolina"
      }
   ],
   getFrequency = function (u) {
      return u.name.length;
   },
   process = function (users) {
    _.forEach ( users , function ( user ) {
      console.log(user);
      var freq = getFrequency(user);
      if(freq) {
        user.frequency = freq;
        usersFromActiveDomains.push(user);
        console.log('user', user);
      } 
    });
    return usersFromActiveDomains;
  }
usersList2 = process(baseUsers);
console.log('baseUsers:',baseUsers);
console.log('usersFromActiveDomains:',usersFromActiveDomains);
console.log('usersList2:',usersList2);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The 'users' that my function receives from an API built using Mongoose. As the Mongoose do have DB schema, does that matter?
This problem is not yet solved, being a naive node.js developer, I think that i'm missing some fundamental point.

Comment: 'users' is only defined inside your function.  That's why I broke the users down into a bunch of different arrays - to show you how the info is stored.  Anyway, it sounds like you want to POST this info back to the server so your edit is stored in the database.  Afraid I can't help more without more specifics of your environment and what you're trying to do.